# How to connect flexible flat cable

Tags: raspberry-pi, connector, hdmi, flexible

I'm trying to connect [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2218) to [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2353). From another question I asked (I can't find it anymore) the cable is a flexible flat cable, and I should pull out the black plastic piece at the bottom right of the picture in the first link, insert the cable, then push the black piece back in. Unfortunately, the black piece isn't going fully back in like it started, and it keeps wiggling out, and the screen doesn't display properly. I know the problem is in the screen because the raspberry pi works fine when connected to a TV.

The screen:

[image]

The connection:

[image][image]

Comment: The flat flex goes between the black plastic piece and the PCB, not between the black plastic piece and the white plastic piece.

Comment: Oh. Well I'm stupid

Comment: Now the screen's just staying black. I wonder how much stupidity is present this time around.

Comment: It's not intuitive just looking at the connector. I learned it the hard way. For black screen, there's a possibility that you damaged the flex by bending it, depending on how fragile it is and how much force you used. But might it also be possible that you tried to insert it the wrong way around?

Comment: I dunno, it looks the same as in the picture. However, the tips of the pins are still showing, is that supposed to happen?

Comment: They're usually not visible. The cable should "bottom out" inside the connector before you tighten the black piece.

Comment: Well, they don't show before I tighten the black piece, so I don't really know if that counts.

Comment: I feel like the cable is in all the way, but now the black piece isn't going in all the way.

Comment: And the screen is still black.